# Select option data_atribute passing value in php variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form which includes:

```
<form action="schedule.php" method="post" id="schedule">

                                      <div class="form-group mb-2" >
                                       <?php $movies = $db->query("SELECT * FROM movies")->fetchAll();?>

                                       <label for="title" class="control-label">Add Movie</label>
                                       <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="title" id="title" data-live-search="true" data-title="Movie name" data-size="5" required>

                                        <?php foreach($movies as $movie): ?>
                                          <option value='<?= $movie['title'] ?>' data-dur='<?= $movie['duration'] ?>'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $movie['title'] ?></option>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                      </select>
                                     </div>

                                <?php
                                 $start_time = "10:30";
                                 $end_time = date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime(''.$dur.' minutes',strtotime($start_time)));

                                 /* NEED: $dur = data-dur='<?= $movie['duration'] ?>' */
                                ?>

                              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
                              <input type="hidden" name="start_time" id="start_time" value="<?= $start_time  ?>">
                              <input type="hidden" name="end_time" id="end_time" value="<?= $end_time?>">

                           </form>
```

I hope this is possible. I've looked around stackoverflow and google for an answer but could not find one for my purpose.

Comment: I see HTML and JavaScript, but no PHP. Does the PHP generate the HTML, and if so, wouldn't you have it already? If not, then how do you want to get it to PHP, using GET/POST or something else?

Comment: Please edit your question, include a php script and explanation, also what desired output you want.